# Stubbing void method using mockito is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito

```
doThrow(new Exception()).when(service.method(anyString(), anyBoolean(), anyString()));
```

Does not working because the method returns void.

```
doThrow(new Exception()).when(service).method(anyString(), anyBoolean(), anyString());
```

Does not stub properly.

The stubbing is:
`method("", false, "")`
instead of `method(<any string>, <any bool>, <any string>)` and I get a stubbing mismatch

```
 - this invocation of 'method' method:
    service.method(
    "ad6b9045-e120-44ed-94df-c8262f19409d",
    false,
    "j39fj230jf390j09jf390"
);
    -> at ....java:108)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. service.method("", false, "");
```

What is going on?

Comment: @M.Deinum there's no method with 4 parameters. What do you mean?

Comment: Wrong count on my part. Did you use the proper matchers? The mockito ones and not by accident others.

Comment: @M.Deinum `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers`

Comment: Then there must be something weird in your setup, as have been using that in different tests for years and works like a charm. Do you have conflicting versions of Mockito?

Comment: @M.Deinum Only 3.5.13

Comment: instead of any try with `isA(String.class), isA(boolean.class), isA(String.class))`. Also please add the actual test and method signature to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum That generates the stubbing `service.method(null, false, null)`

Comment: Did you create a stub or a mock?

Comment: @M.Deinum `service` is a mockito mock.

Comment: As requested before please add the test and method signature. I'm tempted to close this message with too little information.